# Create an excel file in a different directory

Tags: python

```
if not os.path.isdir("DirectoryName"):
    os.makedirs("DirectoryName")

if not os.path.isfile('FileName.xlsx'):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()  
    dest_filename = 'FileName.xlsx'
```

I have the following problem: I want to create a directory in the same directory where I have python files and to create the FileName.xlsx in the directory: DirectoryName and I haven't found out how to do that yet.¿Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Tried using `DirectoryName/FileName.xslx`?

Comment: I've tried this: wb = openpyxl.Workbook('DirectoryName/FileName.xslx')  and it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.5/tutorial.html#saving-to-a-file) says you can `wb.save(os.path.join('DirectoryName', 'FileName.xlsx'), as_template=False)`. With `dest_filename = 'FileName.xlsx'` you just assign value to variable. So try:

```
if not os.path.isdir("DirectoryName"):
    os.makedirs("DirectoryName")

if not os.path.isfile('FileName.xlsx'):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()  
    dest_filename = 'FileName.xlsx' 
    wb.save(os.path.join('DirectoryName', dest_filename), as_template=False)
```

Note that directory where you file is may not be same as you current directory related to which your path is.

Comment: thanks so much. It works but I had to remove: as_template=False

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xlsxwriter module :

```
import xlsxwriter
path = "...";
filename = "file.xlsx";
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path + filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if not os.path.exists("DirectoryName"):
    os.makedirs("DirectoryName")
filepath = 'DirectoryName/FileName.xlsx'
if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook(filepath)  
    wb.save(filename = filepath)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it but I forgot the last code line,sorry. It creates the FileName.xlsx in the same directory where I have python files,not in DirectoryName

Comment: It doesn't work. It creates the Filename.xlsx in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Just use `wb.save(file_path)` to create your workbook.

```
import openpyxl, os

if not os.path.isdir("DirectoryName"):
    os.makedirs("DirectoryName")

file_path = 'DirectoryName/Filename.xlsx'

if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()  # open a workbook
    ws = wb.active  # get the active worksheet

    # do your manipulation

    wb.save(file_path)
```